# Find determinant of $\rm P=A^{2}(7B)^{2}A^{-1}$ if $\rm B^{2}=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$, $B$ $\in M_{2,2}$ nonsingular such that $\rm B^{2}=B$.

Which is the determinant of this given matrix?  $\rm P=A^{2}(7B)^{2}A^{-1}$

I know the correct answer, which is: $\det(P)=7^{4}\det(A)$

The problem is, i have no idea how to get there.

Any hint?

Comment: Do you know any properties of the determinant in connection with scalar or matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Remember that for square matrices, $\det(A_1 A_2) = \det(A_1)\det(A_2)$.  Applying this to $B^2 = B$, what possibilities do we have for $\det(B)$?  How can nonsingularity come into play?  What happens when you apply this to the formula for $P$?

Comment: Indeed there is a mistake, it is $M_{2,2}$. I managed to get to this point: $det(P) = 7^{4}det(A^{2})det(B)det(A^{-1})$. but from there i dont know what else to do.

Comment: What does $B^2 = B$ imply about $\det(B)?$  How is $\det(A^{-1})$ related to $\det(A)$?

Comment: Where does $7^6$ come from, even if $B$ is an idempotent $2 \times 2$ matrix.  Isn't $det(7B)=49$?  Sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @EricFisher, The question originally stated $M_{3,3}$ not $M_{2,2}$, I'm fixing that now.

Comment: I see... so there is not any problem if do this? $det(P)=7^{4}det(AAA^{-1})det(B)$ which is equal to $det(P)=7^{4}det(A)det(B)$ I know there is a relation with $B^{2}=B$ but i can not see it.

Comment: Nevermind i just saw it. $det(B^{2})=det(B)$ thus, $det(B)^{2} - det(B)=0$, finally $det(B)$ has to be 1. am i corrrect?

Comment: @TheNicouU, $\det(B)^2 = \det(B)$ implies $\det(B)$ is either $0$ or $1$, but the fact that it's nonsingular means that $\det(B) = 1$, so yes!